# Wacky Shape Size in DevOps Mermaid Diagrams

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, mermaid

I've got a mermaid diagram in Azure DevOps. I'm using it to create a flowchart. But I've noticed that the shapes are extraordinarily larger than the text they contain.

I tried defining a class and applying it to all the ids in the markdown, to no avail. (I set the margin and padding to zero, reduced the line height and font size, and so on. The shape size did not change.)

Is there a way to control the shape size from Markdown? If so, how do I do that? The diagram works, but its appearance is less than acceptable for presentation purposes.

The Markdown

```
::: mermaid
 graph TD;

   new[New]-->dup;
   dup{Remove?};
     dup--"Yes"-->remove;
     dup--"no"-->nr;
   remove["Removed"];
   nr[Needs Requirements]-->rq;
   rq{Requirements Complete?}-->c;
   c{Critical?};
   c--"Yes"-->sr;
     sr[Scheduled Release] --> a;
       a[Active] --> pqa;
       pqa[Pending QA] --> tp;
       tp{Tests Passed?};
         tp--"Yes"-->rfp["Ready for Production"];
         tp--"No"-->rr["Requires Rework"];
       rr-->pqa;
       rfp-->rfpc["Closed"];
   c--"No"-->bl;
     bl[Product Backlog]-->sr;
   classDef sm font-size:9pt,padding:0,margin:0,border-width:1px,line-height:1em;
   class new,dup,dupNote,remove,nr,rq,c,sr,a,pqa,tp,rfp,rr,pqa,rfpc,bl sm;
:::
```

Comment: Could you share a piece of sample styling code?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I've added the complete markdown. The class definition and its application (as described on github) are at the bottom. Thank you!

Comment: The default styling seems have a better appearance. i also noticed  box `rq` is extraordinarily larger. The best i can do now is to break the text into two lines using <br/> `rq{Requirements <br/> Complete?}`

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Even with `<br/>` tags (which was my first approach) the shapes are significantly larger than the text. I was hoping to style things so that the appearance wasn't so ghastly. Does the current implementation just not support styling the way that the github page implies?

Comment: Seems currently it's not supported to style the shape.